# Writing to current file

Tags: python, file, file-io, io

I was trying to see if there is any way to write to the current file, in which code is being executed.

This is the code I wrote:

```
with open(__file__, 'r+') as f:
    f.write('abc')
```

It does not work. Is there any way I can use python to write to the file in which code is being executed?

Comment: do u get an error or does the updated code have no effect? what error do u get?

Comment: Your code works for me as well.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you write to the current module file? The module has *already* been read by Python by the time the code executes. *It does not work* is not a proper problem description.

Comment: no error. Its just that nothing happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I expect `abc` to appear in the file.

Comment: @xylon97: And how did you verify that `abc` does not appear in the file? **Why** are you trying to write to the current module source file? What are you trying to achieve, beyond writing to that file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I am just playing with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this. My file `test.py`, after execution, is

```
abch open(__file__, 'r+') as f:
    f.write('abc')
```

which tells me that the program worked "as designed".

Comment: What are you using? I'm using sublime text 2

Comment: Python 3.3.0 - but that's irrelevant. How exactly are you running your program?

Comment: Ctrl + Enter is the shortcut I've set for running the code and I am using python 2.7.3.

Comment: Did you *look* at the source code for your program after execution? Perhaps your editor doesn't automatically refresh if a file is modified outside of it?

Comment: Yes, I closed and re-opened the file after running, and still no `abc`.

Comment: Does your editor log Python interpreter errors? Does it lock the files it has opened? If the answer to the first question is no and the answer to the second question is yes, then that's your problem - Python is kept from writing to the file because it's in use.

Comment: Yes, sublime text 2 has a console, where the output, as well as errors are logged. I don't know about locking. Anyways, I'll let it be.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the file:

```
with open(__file__, 'a') as f:
f.write('abc')
```